# Can't adjust div position?

Tags: html, css

I'm  having an issue that I'm sure is my fault somewhere. I can't get the divs to move the way I want them to. I am trying to make Div GIS1 centered directly in the middle of the page, but when I put it at 50% it goes past the middle of the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/380vbxqe/

```
#wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position:absolute;
}

#GIS1_text{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
#GIS1{
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-left: 50%;
    width:50%;


}
#street_thumb{
    vertical-align:middle;
    max-height: 300px;
    max-width: 400px;

}
```

Comment: Whoops. Posted now. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Horizontally center a div in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div)

Comment: I'm trying to do it with percentages only to make it dynamic. (works on all platforms)

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. The method described in the duplicate question is a) dynamic and b) works on all platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
margin-left: 50%;
```

means the `div` starts at the middle of the page, not that it's centered.

Try using

```
margin: auto;
```

instead

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnfsmile/380vbxqe/2/) (border on div to show whole size)

Comment: Wow, thanks for the fast response. One more question for you: the image won't center inside its div (street_thumb inside GIS1). Any idea? http://jsfiddle.net/380vbxqe/7/

Comment: Try giving the `div` a `text-align: center;`

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

On the div you want to center.

Comment: Wouldn't `margin: auto;` be better?

Comment: Since the OP set the divs margin-top to 10%, I assumed he only wanted to center it horizontally.

Comment: As far as I know, `margin: auto` [does not affect vertical margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/margin#Valeurs). :)

Comment: You are correct, however it would still overwrite the margin-top value if it was set before.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `margin:auto` in `GIS1`:

```
#GIS1
{
  margin:auto;
  width:50%;
}
```

See [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/380vbxqe/1/)